# How do I prevent Excel from asking if I'm sure I want to save in ODS format each time?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

How do I prevent Excel from asking if I'm sure I want to save in another format each time?

[image: excel dialog]

I tried to change one of the options, but could not find one about saving prompts.

[image: excel options]

Comment: I get the same prompt when saving in CSV format. If you want to always ignore the warning, I think you will need to use VBA code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To suppress the warning message:

- Start `regedit`
- Navigate to the following location (substitute `16` with your Office version number):

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options
  ```
- Right-click on the right and select *New > DWORD*
- Rename as `DisableSaveAsLossWarningOpenDocumentSpreadsheet`
- Double-click it and set its value to `1`

Comment: So nice. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

This would be the `.reg` file to apply the change:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options]
"DisableSaveAsLossWarningOpenDocumentSpreadsheet"=dword:00000001
```

Sorry for the trivial post, but I'm lazy :-)